# React app with google maps api doesn't show up or import the list's options text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Okay so I created this app in code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/olj1r44roq and my list menu is having trouble with importing or showing the locations on the menu.

[Image link showing the list. Each option exists and its focusable but has no text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV7QX.png)

Here is my code on the matter:

```js
import * as **currentLocations** from "./locations.json";

    class Filter extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          **locationsFiltered**: **currentLocations**.default,
        };
      }
updateLocations = query => {
    //Handling the state of the locations
    let updateThis = this;
    let fLocations;
    let fMarkers;

    if (query) {
      const match = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(query), "i");

      // Adding a location to the array if its the same as the query
      fLocations = this.props.list.filter(location =>
        match.test(location.title)
      );

      this.setState({
        **locationsFiltered**: fLocations,
        markersFiltered: fMarkers
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        **locationsFiltered**: this.props.list,
        markersFiltered: this.props.markers
      });
    }
render() {
    const { query, **locationsFiltered**, listOpened } = this.state;
 {listOpened && (
          <ul className="locations-list">
            {**locationsFiltered**.map(location => (
              .....
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: why don't you use react-google-maps. It is component based and easier to understand. Let me know If you don't have issue so I can share some code snippet from react-google maps.

Comment: Hey @SakhiMansoor ! Unfortunately I have a close deadline on this one and since the previous mistake (the one you commented for) was some logic I had wrong I really don't want to rewrite this app with the react-google-maps dependency etc. However after reading the documentation and seeing it in action myself I will use it on my future projects. Too sad I didn't know it existed before I started this one. Thanks for taking the time to answer. Wishing you the best!

Comment: You shouldn't be storing props in state. It is a react anti-pattern.